# An indent for each line in file

Tags: python, indentation

I have to read each line in a file with indent. 
Here's what I have, but it's not working...

```
    f = open("filename.txt", "r")
    print("\t" + f.read())
```

The indent only applies to the first line.

Comment: To help others answer your question better, include details on _why_ this is not working. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The .read() method returns the entire contents of a file. The method you want is .readlines(), which returns a list containing each line separately. The code you want looks more like this:

```
f = open("filename.txt")
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    print("\t" + line)
```

Additionally, open() reads by default, so including 'r' isn't necessary. Enjoy coding!

Comment: Even better: forget `readlines` and iterate over the file object with `for line in f:`. When you use `readlines` the whole file must be buffered in memory.

Comment: I completely forgot that existed. That doesn't get rid of trailing whitespace and newlines, though, but neither does .readlines(). You might want to use line.strip() instead of line, @Hello18.